# PHP file upload - multiple files

Tags: php, file-upload, multiple-instances

using the following PHP I am attempting to upload multiple images. The number of images upload can be varied.

The problem that I seem to have is that image number 1 isn't being uploaded however it's filepath is being printed to the screen.

The code:-

```
if ($_FILES['pac_img_1']['name']>""){
    echo("You have uploaded the following images:-<ul>");
    for ($i=1; $i<=$imagesCount; $i++){ 
        $target_path = "files/" . $companyName . "/images/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['pac_img_' . $i]['name']); 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pac_img_' . $i]['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "<li><a href='". $target_path . "'>".  basename( $_FILES['pac_img_' . $i]['name']). "</a></li>";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading an image";
        }
};
    echo("</ul>");
}else{
    echo("None uploaded");
};
```

I have adapted it from some code that I've used before so I suspect I am guilty of a "schoolboy" error here.

Help would be appreciated.

Edit to add that $imagesCount takes its value from a form element via a $_POST request. When only one image is uploaded that value = 0.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the directories do exist on the server and that they have write permissions. Indeed any image other than the first will upload fine.

Comment: I prematurely thought that I had the solution based on the initial answers - Thanks for those :) - However I'm still encountering the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your for loop need to be modified. Array indexes starts from 0. And the last element should be Array length - 1;
>   Your for loop need to be modified as bellow code sample.

Actually, it's looping through several $_POST itens. His HTML probably has something like:

```
<input type="file" name="pac_img_1">
<input type="file" name="pac_img_2">
<input type="file" name="pac_img_3">
```

and he is trying to get these images.

I would do this differently.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="pac_img[]" />
<input type="file" name="pac_img[]" />
<input type="file" name="pac_img[]" />
```

(note that you can dynamically add file inputs without worrying about names)

PHP:

```
if (count($_FILES['pac_img']) > 0){
    echo("You have uploaded the following images:-<ul>");

    foreach($_FILES['pac_img'] as $key => $file){
        $target_path = "files/" . $companyName . "/images/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $file['name']); 
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "<li><a href='". $target_path . "'>".  basename( $file['name'] ). "</a></li>";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading an image";
        }
    }
    echo("</ul>");
}else{
    echo("None uploaded");
}
```

And last, but not least: ALWAYS check if uploaded files are what they suposed to be. (http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This didn't fix my issue when I tried it. But I have managed to fix it myself. When I am able to answer my own question I will detail how. Also many thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Without being a php-dude at all, I'd try changing

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$imagesCount; $i++){
```

to

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$imagesCount; $i++){
```

-or maybe

```
for ($i=0; $i < $imagesCount; $i++){
```

depending on how $imagesCount is set.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop need to be modified. Array indexes starts from 0. And the last element should be Array length - 1;

Your for loop need to be modified as bellow code sample.

```
if ($_FILES['pac_img_1']['name']>""){
    echo("You have uploaded the following images:-<ul>");
    for ($i=0; $i<$imagesCount; $i++){ 
        $target_path = "files/" . $companyName . "/images/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['pac_img_' . $i]['name']); 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pac_img_' . $i]['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "<li><a href='". $target_path . "'>".  basename( $_FILES['pac_img_' . $i]['name']). "</a></li>";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading an image";
        }
};
    echo("</ul>");
}else{
    echo("None uploaded");
};
```

Comment: when does he use i to reference a non key array index? i though the i is concatenated to the string refering to the filename?

Comment: According to his example he uses $i as index. It's a default key index for that as well. And only issue is the declaration of his for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still not getting the first image uploaded.